# Повторное использование переменных

Tags: c++, c, code-style

Я завел переменную типа `int` с осмысленным именем `count` (счет), потом использовал ее по назначению.

Дальше в коде потребовалась переменная с типом `int` - правильно ли использовать эту же переменную(`count`) ведь она уже не нужна, а только занимает память.

Проблема в том, что у нее есть правильное имя которое уже не соответствует в текущей реализации. Что правильней - задействовать ее или завести новую?

Comment: Вероятно, это не совсем правильное имя, если в одном и том же контексте оно несет два значения. Подумайте о разных именах в стиле `appleCount` и `orangeCount`.

Comment: > уже не нужна, а только занимает память. 

ничего не занимает. Компилятор умный, сам разберётся как лучше жонглировать стеком.

Comment: @eigenein: правильные имена -- 50% предотвращённых ошибок.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Испаользование одной переменной для разных целей - это  неправильно. 
Во-первых, вы, я вас уверяю, скорее всего не столкнетесь с такой ситуацией, когда лишние 4 байта (или сколько ваш компилятор будет задействовать для хранения int'a) могут сыграть большую роль. (более того, я могу вам гарантировать, что будет миллион случаев, где вы успешно потратите впустую куда большие объемы памяти и даже не обратите на это внимание)

Во-вторых, (и в главных) такая экономия ни к чему хорошему не приведет - переменная должна использоваться только для одной цели, использовать ее в нескольких целях чревато серьезными проблемами. Скорее всего, если вы будете применять эту порочную практику в сколько-нибудь больших проектах, вы однажды просто используете "старое" значение переменной в "новых" целях просто из-за невнимательности, а это может привести к самым непредсказуемым последствиям.
Вот пример: предположим, вы пишете программу для какого-нибудь кардиостимулятора. Из желаний сэкономить память вы в одной и той же переменной храните сначала частоту сердцебиения, а потом,в другой части программы, посчитав, что вам эта частота уже не нужна, вы пишете в нее какую-нибудь концентрацию сахара в крови. А потом, забыв, о вышесказанном, снова используете переменную в первоначальном значении. Обнаружив, что частота сердцебиения снизилась с 80 ударов в секунду до, скажем 0.0005, ваш кардиостимулятор предполагает, что человеку очень плохо, и начинает что-то там делать, отчего человеку очень плохо становится уже по-настоящему. 
В действительности, я понятия не имею, как работают кардиостимуляторы, и, скорее всего, я тут много приврал, но так или иначе, эта ваша практика может привести к чему-то подобному, описанному выше

Comment: @DreamChild, для одной переменной все это безусловно правильно.

А вот что делать, если речь пойдет о **большом** вспомогательном массиве? Даже не важно, в стеке или куче.

Понятно, что доступ к этой памяти надо организовать в разных местах  через указатели с разными именами. 

Но все же? Что тут делать с чистотой идеи?

Comment: @avp: Большой вспомогательный массив нельзя просто так использовать для разных значений. Я бы сделал специальные функции наподобие mymalloc/myfree (которые кешируют полученную от системы память), но ни при каких обстоятельствах не использовал один и тот же массив/указатель для двух разных вещей.

Comment: @VladD, а если *ни при каких случаях* вызывает paging на сервере?

Вот из-за таких "академических" установок иногда производительность программ отличается на порядок.

Comment: @avp: встречный вам вопрос: а если разбиение программы на процедуры (даже не на классы) вызывает paging, сливать всё в одну простыню? (Вы знаете же, я сторонник оптимизации на уровне алгоритмов.)

---
В любом случае мне кажется, что подобными низкоуровневыми оптимизациями должен заниматься транслятор, а не программист.

Comment: @avp, думаю, если на сервере `paging` только от того, что есть дубли массивов, значит стоит подумать о том, что такая нагрузка на алгоритм не соответствует планируемой. Придется переписывать весь алгоритм, учитывая такую нагрузку. В общем случае, я не верю, что в любой ситуации можно написать алгоритм без каких-то издержек. При оптимизации всегда приходится чем-то жертвовать: скоростью, памятью, логикой.

Comment: @VladD, про функции пример явно натянутый. Скорее здесь может идти речь о выборе между рекурсией и итерацией. 

Простыню из кода делать никогда не надо (точно работать не будет).

--

Транслятор может и должен всякой оптимизацией заниматься, но хорошо не может.

--

MyMalloc вещь хорошая, но не настолько простая. С ним ведь начнутся обобщения и т.д., он разрастется (а Вы ведь знаете, как все любят читать документацию) и сам станет таким же источноиком ошибок, как и *локальный для функции* массив для разных целей.

--

@mega, вот про неизбежные издержки - это очень верно.

Answer (score 9):

Если Вы не пишете какой-то stable-алгоритм, то правильней использовать новую переменную, а оптимизацию оставить для компилятора.

Comment: краткость сестра таланта

Answer (score 4):

Идеальный вариант:
Весь текст программы разбит на функции. Каждая функция выполняет свою работу*, и не лезет, куда не надо. Функции относительно маленькие*, и не содержат большое количество переменных. Переменные в функциях локальные, или принадлежать к определенному пространству имен*.

Если вы будете следовать этим правилам, то подобные вопросы у вас не возникнут.

---

1. Если вы хотите сделать функцию, складывающую два числа, то она должна только складывать эти два числа и ничего больше.
2. Маленькие функции понятие растяжимое. Кто-то считает, что функция не должна быть больше 30 строк, кто-то считает, что она должна целиком помещаться на экране, и тд и тп.
3. Распределяя переменные между пространствами имен, вы можете создать переменную "count" для подсчета количества ударов сердца, и в тоже время использовать такую же переменную "count", но из другого пространства, для подсчета объема перелитой крови. Ох уж эти кардиостимуляторы...

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы используете свой `count` просто для итерации по массивам, с однократным использованием в одном месте сразу после цикла, то лучше переименйте его в `i`,`j` или `k` и используйте сколько душе угодно.

Если переменная цикла не используется после него, то наверное лучше не лениться и определить ее в начале `for (int i = ...`.

В других случаях лучше ее повторно не использовать.

Абсолютно недопустимо повторное использование в разных целях статических и особенно глобальных переменных.

Comment: Не уверен насчет циклов, я все же предпочитаю си-стиль объявления переменных, когда они все в одном месте - в начале функции. Это удобно для понимания, когда следует извлечь класс или новый метод. И обвести взглядом все локальные ресурсы так гораздо проще.  
 --  
`for (int i` удобно использовать в очевидных местах, например: когда функция/метод состоит только из одного цикла, а других локальных ресурсов не использует